# Excel VBA - how to display the SQL results on a specific cell?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:.., Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

so instead the sql results will display starting in **A1**, i would like to specify it depending on what the value inside the cell **B1** for example

---

i tried this:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:..,Destination:=Range("A1").value)
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Range("A1").value` is returning a `String` containing "B1" instead of a `Range` object representing the B1 position.

Try this instead:
`ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:..,Destination:=Range(Range("A1").value))`